# Terminal 3 to Terminal 5

Tags: visas, uk, transit, lhr, sudanese-citizens

do I need a transit UK visa to move from terminal 3 to terminal 5? I am a Sudanese traveling to the USA from Bahrain via British airways, my flight stat that I will switch terminals in Heathrow airport within the same calendar day